# Keyboard Logi k600

Tags: logitech

I have a keyboard Logi k600. I use Solaar app but it does not find my keyboard. I use a wireless USB which it has the keyboard.
It does not work neither by wireless USB nor by Bluetooth.

I use Xubuntu:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: is there any keyboard with touchpad usb wireless compatible with Ubuntu?.

Comment: Have you set it up for Windows, MacOS or some smart TV? It should work with the "Windows" settings but you tell us.

Comment: Sorry. I have only ubuntu in my computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting for Ubuntu should be the same as for [Windows](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/k600.html#/devices/windows):

1. Press <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> for **3 seconds**
2. The LED on the <kbd>1</kbd> key should light up for 5 seconds